# Ajuda sobre Perguntas... no beta privado?

Tags: bug, status-pronto, beta, central-de-ajuda

1. No site principal, clique no botão "Faça uma pergunta".
2. Observe o link "Ajuda sobre Perguntas »" na área cinza à direita.
3. Clique neste link.
4. Você chegará na seguinte página: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask-beta
   Esta página tem o seguinte título: "Como perguntar no beta privado". O conteúdo da página não tem nada a ver com a nossa situação atual e um iniciante que chegar nesta página decerto ficará no mínimo confuso, ou talvez amedrontado.
5. O link correto deveria ser https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Argh, esse é f... feio. Ainda bem que ninguém lê páginas de ajuda :)

Comment: Só uma coisa, parte do conteúdo ainda tem a ver com o nosso site na situação atual. Ou deveria.

Comment: @bfavaretto Então talvez seja o caso de modificar o texto do não-beta para englobar tudo.

Comment: Concordo. Eu gosto deste trecho: *[evite] pesquisas, escrutínios e perguntas rudimentares como “quais são alguns livros bons sobre este tópico” ou “quais são os melhores blogs sobre este tópico”. Estas não são boas perguntas para o beta privado – elas não refletem o conteúdo real que desejamos neste site e não são representativas dele.* Mas tenho dúvidas se isso ainda vale como posição "oficial" hoje.

Comment: @bfavaretto Independente de serem a posição "oficial", pelo visto elas não são um problema no site

Comment: Eu não tenho como resolver o problema, infelizmente. Vou ter que mandar para um dev e esperar.